# New battery not recognized

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, freeze, battery, device-manager

I have Acer Aspire 5750. Recently I replaced my 4400 mAh, 6 cell battery with new one, 6600 mAh, 9 cell, compatible battery. Since than, when my notebook restarts, or turns on, I have to wait for 15 minutes because it is not responding to any command(freezes). After that I hear some "notification" sound and it all works properly. Also, in device manager battery is not recognized. I have to "Scan for new devices" and than it is recognized and I see the battery notification in my windows notification area.

Any idea why this is happening and any possible solution maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds as if you have purchased an aftermarket battery rather than an OEM battery. Many companies now have ways to detect the difference and will hobble non-OEM batteries.

If this is the case, you probably will have to purchase the more expensive OEM battery.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I believe i have bought the non-OEM battery that is true. Are you saying that Acer(or my computer) knows that the new battery is non OEM and is making problems because of that? If there is some pre-installed software that checks that before I start my notebook isn't it logical that I can somehow "take care" of that ?

Comment: I don't have the knowledge to explain it, but I am sure you can find out more just by searching such as "using non-oem batteries Acer", etc. Good luck.